# apt-get error when installing git

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, git, apt-get

I just set up a fresh Ubuntu 12.04.5 server amd64 machine on VirtualBox 4.2 (I was having install issues on OSX 10.10 using 4.3) and I'm able to do `apt-get install curl` but when I run `apt-get install git` I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What's going on here? Is my `sources.list` file broke on a fresh install?

NOTE: I thought this was specific, to `git`, but there were other packages that weren't working either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried `apt-get update` but this gave me some more errors. I eventually had to do `rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to delete everything then run `apt-get update` to add everything back (and cleanup whatever might have been broken in there) and I was off and running.

Answer (score 1):

Try running: "apt-get update"

and then try again.

If it still fails, paste the contents of your source.list here.

Comment: I can't remember what the error was, but it essentially said it can't find some things. I had to keep digging deeper